# TPM with Trousers Installation Issue

Tags: ubuntu, tpm

I would like to setup my TPM for disk encryption. I have Intel NUC7i5DNKE computers which has a TPM 2.0. This is a clean desktop install Ubuntu 16.04.5 on the machine with kernel version 4.15.0-29.

Here is what's happening. Can anyone any idea what's wrong? I would be very grateful if you give a hand. Thanks!

```
root@deniz-NUC7i5DNKE:/home/deniz/linux-luks-tpm-boot# sudo apt-get 

install trousers tpm-tools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
trousers is already the newest version (0.3.13-4).
tpm-tools is already the newest version (1.3.8-2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_TIME = "sv_SE.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "sv_SE.UTF-8",
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LC_ADDRESS = "sv_SE.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "sv_SE.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "sv_SE.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "sv_SE.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "sv_SE.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "sv_SE.UTF-8",
    LC_PAPER = "sv_SE.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_US.UTF-8").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Setting up trousers (0.3.13-4) ...
Job for trousers.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status trousers.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript trousers, action "start" failed.
● trousers.service - LSB: starts tcsd
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/trousers; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-10-23 16:54:53 CEST; 3ms ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 28138 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/trousers start (code=exited, status=30)

Oct 23 16:54:53 deniz-NUC7i5DNKE systemd[1]: Starting LSB: starts tcsd...
Oct 23 16:54:53 deniz-NUC7i5DNKE trousers[28138]:  * Starting Trusted Computing daemon tcsd
Oct 23 16:54:53 deniz-NUC7i5DNKE tcsd[28144]: TCSD TDDL[28144]: TrouSerS ioctl: (25) Inappropriate ioctl for device
Oct 23 16:54:53 deniz-NUC7i5DNKE tcsd[28144]: TCSD TDDL[28144]: TrouSerS Falling back to Read/Write device support.
Oct 23 16:54:53 deniz-NUC7i5DNKE trousers[28138]:    ...fail!
Oct 23 16:54:53 deniz-NUC7i5DNKE systemd[1]: trousers.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=30
Oct 23 16:54:53 deniz-NUC7i5DNKE systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: starts tcsd.
Oct 23 16:54:53 deniz-NUC7i5DNKE systemd[1]: trousers.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 23 16:54:53 deniz-NUC7i5DNKE systemd[1]: trousers.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
dpkg: error processing package trousers (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of tpm-tools:
 tpm-tools depends on trousers; however:
  Package trousers is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package tpm-tools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 trousers
 tpm-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

PS. I already activated the TPM and the NUC PC I have has TPM2.0 according to its spec.

Comment: Also see [The TPM2 Software Stack: Introducing a Major Open Source Release](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2018/08/29/tpm2-software-stack-open-source) on Intel's site. The blog lists the software to use with TPM2.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to set up luks with trousers, but you have a TPM 2.0 chip. Trousers, being a TSS implementation for TPM 1.2, does not work with TPM 2.0 (just TPM 1.2). So you will have to install a TPM 2.0 TSS, or a compatible set of tools, and make it work with luks. [tpm2-tss](https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tss) is a good place to start, and this is a nice list of steps to set up the rest: https://github.com/vchatterji/tpm2-luks